# Store select query as variable and loop for entire variable

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to store the result of select query from another table and set it as variable. Then i want to loop through the variable and use it in my loop for. The question is how i can store the result of select query from my table?

```
do $$
declare
 ids <data_type> := <SELECT DISTINCT (*) from a>;
begin 
for id in ids loop
insert
 into
 b (
 select from c where c.id in id
end loop;
end $$
```

Comment: You don't need a loop or PL/pgSQL for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not run a single query?

```
insert into b ( . . . )
    select . . .
    from c
    where c.id in (select id from a);
```

The `. . .` are for listing the columns/expressions for the `insert`.